# MuPAD: plot sum of list elements

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, symbolic-computation

I am receiving an unclear error when trying to plot partial sums of elements of a list in MuPAD. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
d := [1, 2, 3]:
plot::Sum(d[i], i = 1..nops(d)):
```

> Error: Duplicate identifiers '{d[i]}' were found in range specifications. [plot::Sum::new]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, [`plot::Sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/plot-sum.html) expects an expression (or a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/function.html)) for the first argument, but you're passing it a [list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/lists.html) (`DOM_LIST`). You can easily create a function/procedure using the [`->` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/proc.html):

```
d := [1, 2, 3]:
plot(plot::Sum(i->d[i], i = 1..nops(d))):
```

This produces a plot like this:

[image: plot]

Comment: I was considering something like that, but did not try it as the documentation examples (http://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/plot-sum.html) were not in that format.

Comment: Additionally, the original format I provided works if a matrix is used, rather than a list. Would you be able to explain why?